# DropDownListFor optionLabel null gives "call is ambiguous"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Out of curiosity, since it is easy to work around: [this documentation for `DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) says that `optionLabel` can be `null`. However if I try to compile with `optionLabel` as `null` I get a *call is ambiguous* error, because there is also a method that take an `object` in the same position and `null` is obviously ambiguous. So is a) the documentation wrong b) there a way to compile and specify which method I mean c) the documentation means a different method where `optionLabel` can be `null` without causing a *call is ambiguous* error?

EDIT:

I now realise that of course the documentation means situations where `optionLabel` is passed as a string variable, it makes no sense to always pass in `null`. eg:

```
string optionLabel = null;

// Possibly do something with optionLabel

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, selectList, optionLabel)
```

Comment: can you share how you are calling it? do you have any other extension methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. You cannot have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Value, Model.Values, null)
```

because this is ambiguous with the [`following overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Alternatively if you insist so much to pass null you could use named parameters to disambiguate the overload:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, new SelectList(null), optionLabel: null)
```

Personally I often use named parameters to make the code more readable because of the gazillions of overloads that Microsoft wrote for HTML helpers.

Comment: The value can still be `null`; you just have to give some sort of hint like `(string)null` to tell the compiler which overload you're looking for.

Comment: I prefer to use named parameters in this case as it makes the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about named parameters or using `(string)null`. Would you call that a typed null?

Comment: I wouldn't; a null constant doesn't have a type - that syntax just tells the compiler which overload to pick.

Comment: Ah, but you can pass in null in a string variable. I guess that's what the documentation means.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps convertion to string would resolve the issue?

```
 optionLabel:(string)null
```

Comment: This looks rather Objective-C'y :-)